# IIS - Resource not found while Directory is browsable

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-7

I have a little strange issue on my system. I have hosted a Service, Rest Service (Be Specific) on my system. When I try to access the svc page of the same service it gives me HTTP 404 (The resource cannot be found.) error while I can browse the whole directory and in that directory it shows that the svc file lies with in the folder but when I click on svc file i get the 404 error.

I tried to host the same service on other system and it works fine. I am not sure what causing it not to display on my system.

Any clue would be great help.